# Ng-model is not updated in my form when resetting model

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing some trouble with form as my model is lost when reseting it. Plunker to see issue result : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQ7v23o4FyCLi1eAupsN?p=preview).

```
function cancel() {
    vm.selectedCommande = angular.copy(originalCommande);
    $scope.commandeForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.commandeForm.$setUntouched();
}
```

I'm probably missing something but I can't figure it and I'll appreciate somme help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use type="reset" in your form. If you want to reset form from angularJS, remove that attr from button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
function cancel() {
   vm.selectedCommande.observations = 'Former observations';
   $scope.commandeForm.$setPristine();
   $scope.commandeForm.$setUntouched();
} 
});
```